# ASP.NET Application sample code: difficult json response

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, rest

I choose ASP.NET Web Application and then Web API. I leave the Authentication at "**Individual User Accounts**" and create the project.

I have made no additional changes except to add an ajax call to `api/Account/Register`.

When I make a request with a password that is too simple I get the json response below - it seems really hard to work with.

Is there some method for working with this, or do I really need to access `textStatus.responseJSON.ModelState.\_empty\_[0]` to get a nice text response from this?  Will all error messages follow this general response format for ASP.Net Application rest requests?

PS: Actually I don't even know how to deal with a property called `\_empty\_` as `textStatus.responseJSON.ModelState.\_empty\_[0]` doesn't even work.

My `textStatus` object:

```
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "{\"Message\":\"The request is invalid.\",\"ModelState\":{\"\":[\"Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z').\"]}}",
    "responseJSON": {
        "Message": "The request is invalid.",
        "ModelState": {
            "_empty_": [
                "Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z')."
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "Bad Request"
}
```

UPDATE:

This is the actual body of the response.

But I still don't know how to access the property whose name is "". And, I want to be sure that this is how all error messages will be returned to me.

```
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "": [
            "Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one uppercase ('A'-'Z')."
        ]
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

This seems to parse it pretty well. Is this about as good as it gets?

```
error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var json = textStatus.responseJSON;
    var message = json.Message;
    if (json.ModelState) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.ModelState[''].length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) message += "\n";
            message += "\n" + json.ModelState[''][i];
        }
    }
    alert(message);
}
```

Comment: What's your register action look like?  Is this an actual WebApi controller response or an MVC controller response?

Comment: the class is "public class AccountController : ApiController".

Comment: This is created automatically when you create a project in Visual Studio 2013 using the steps I described.